# Web Services Explorer error 500

Tags: eclipse, web-services

Using latest version of eclipse (Luna) java ee download, I receive a HTTP ERROR: 500 when starting the Web Services Explorer.  There are no messages / faults in the console.  Firewalls (Windows and AV) are turned off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please report that to Eclipse bugtracker https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Webservices ? That would be very nice for other Eclipse users who face the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked around this by changing JAVA_HOME and path to point to 1.7 JDK as the default for Eclipse.  Perhaps Luna is not as Java 8 ready as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

Install JDK 1.7 and uninstall JDK 1.8. That worked for me.